# FirebaseUI does not provide 'displayName' on 'Sign in with Apple'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebaseui, sign-in-with-apple

I recently added `appleAuthProvider()` on FirebaseUI using Swift on iOS. I enabled sign-in method `Apple` in Firebase Console, and add `Sign in with Apple` Capability.

All good so far, but when `authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?)` is called from delegate, the user from `authDataResult`, and also from `Auth.auth().currentUser` have the value `displayName` not set, or `nil`.

Do you guys, have a solution or a workaround to make it work? Firebase only provides email from user and the `displayName` is required for me.

I'll let the code bellow.

```swift
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        authUI?.shouldHideCancelButton = true
        authUI?.delegate = delegate
        authUI?.tosurl = Constants.Url.kFirebaseTermsOfService
        authUI?.privacyPolicyURL = Constants.Url.kFirebasePrivacyPolicy
        
        let emailAuth = FUIEmailAuth()
        let facebookAuth = FUIFacebookAuth(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"])
        let googleAuth = FUIGoogleAuth()
        
        var providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [emailAuth, facebookAuth, googleAuth]
        if useAnonymous {
            let anonymousAuth = FUIAnonymousAuth()
            providers.append(anonymousAuth)
        }

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appleAuth = FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider()
            providers.append(appleAuth)
        }
        
        authUI?.providers = providers
```

Here the firebase delegate method.

```swift
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        
        if let result = authDataResult, let userInfo = result.additionalUserInfo {
            if userInfo.isNewUser {
                let username: String
                if result.user.isAnonymous {
                    let usernameNumber = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) * Int.random(in: 1...9)).suffix(6)
                    username = "Guest\(usernameNumber)"
                } else {
                    username = result.user.displayName ?? "" // displayName is nil here
                }
                var data = [
                    "username" : username
                ]

                // Do something here
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4393